# Imported fbx with armature behaves weird in blender

Tags: armature, bones, import, .fbx

I tried to import a posed model from dazstudio into blender but somehow the armatures are pretty messed up. Any help is appreciated! >.<

This is in dazstudio:
[image]

This one is in blender:
[image]

I tried to adjust some of the import settings in blender but none of them seems to work.
These are my current settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a rest pose equivalent in DAZ you can try to export / import?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Makehuman (http://makehumancommunity.org) or Manuel Bastioni Lab (http://www.manuelbastioni.com) these plugins are both free and Manuel Bastioni is fully integrated inside Blender, is really worth to check it out.

I had a similar issue importing FBX poses from Mixamo, the bones came all wrong, so what I did was:

1- import the pose without skin from mixamo into blender.

2- export that same pose as a BVH file from blender. (Can you export BVH from DAZ Studio?)

3- import a character from Makehuman into blender then apply the BVH to this character.

Hope it helps.